# Transfer Function

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, transfer-function

Hi Guys I am trying to evaluate the following transfer function below can anyone verify if this is correct

[image]

$$e_i = -d_{r,i} + d_i $$
$$d_i = q_{i-1}-q_i$$
$$d_{r,i} =H_iq_i$$
$$Therefore, e_i = -Hiq_i + q_{i-1} - q_i$$
$$q_i = e_iPDG_i$$
$$q_i = PDG_i(-H_iq_i+q_{i-1}-q_i)$$
$$q_i = -PDG_iH_iq_i+PDG_iq_{i-1}-PDG_iq_i$$
$$\frac{q_i}{q_{i-1}} = \frac{PDG}{1+HPDG+PDG}$$

Im thinking this is incorrect but I'm hoping someone can verify this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the error equation have $-H_iq_i$ instead of $H_iq_i$?
$$e_i=−d_{r,i}+d_i$$
$$d_i=q_{i−1}−q_i$$
$$−d_{r,i}=−H_iq_i$$
Therefore (modified equation):
$$e_i=-H_iq_i+q_{i−1}−q_i$$
$$q_i=e_iPDG_i$$
$$q_i=PDG_i(-H_iq_i+q_{i−1}−q_i)$$
$$q_i=-PDG_iH_iq_i+PDG_iq_{i−1}−PDG_iq_i$$
$$\frac{q_i}{q_{i−1}}=\frac{PDG_i}{1+H_iPDG_i+PDG_i}$$

Comment: Yes was making edits and realized my mistake but thank you for the assistance @wicked stat